# Яндекса.Алиса + Касса/Деньги?

Tags: яндекс-касса, яндекс-алиса

Есть навык Алисы для оформления заказов, сейчас оплата происходит при получении товара наличными. Можно ли как-то подключить Яндекс.Кассу/Деньги для электронной оплаты?

Comment: Вау :) научить ее предлагать нажать кнопку 'Оплатить ОнЛайн' ? :) голосом..

Comment: @NewView это конечно можно, но тогда интеграция с Алисой теряет задуманную простоту, отсутствие кликов. И главное, на половине платформ, где есть Алиса, нет экрана/браузера (станция, навигатор), а на них наши целевые покупатели. Поэтому в идеале хотелось бы, чтобы оплата произошла устно из Алисы, если у юзера подключены Яндекс.Деньги.

Comment: А вы интересовались, есть ли интерфейс Алисы к ЯДеньгам? Думаю из соображений приватности этого просто нет,тем более что почти всегда надо вводить подтверждение через смс при заходе...

Comment: @NewView мы конечно пытались погуглить, но у них всяких сервисов и статей по ним очень много, поэтому могли что-то упустить и решили уточнить у ИТ сообщества.

Comment: Подтверждение конечно нужно, но возможно с учётом того, что оба сервиса принадлежат одной компании, у них есть встроенная интеграция с более подходящими для данной сферы юз кейсами. Например, чтобы Алиса сама подтверждала согласие на оплату, и разработчик не получал никаких секретных данных, лишь перевод на свой счёт и уведомление об успешной транзакции. На мой взгляд, вполне реалистичный вариант, было бы круто, будь он уже реализован :)

Comment: Задайте им прямой вопрос в службу технической поддержки - это самый быстрый и правильный путь.

Comment: @NewView спасибо за совет, как-то не додумался до такой банальности  То ли бы слишком долгий рабочий день, то ли привык, что ответа от ИТ-гигантов вроде Facebook и Google крайне сложно добиться. От Яндекса ответ уже получен.